# How to reduce the padding from multiple headers tag one after the other?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, padding, styling

I want to reduce the padding between continues header tag.
Eg : I have header tag with padding H1- 30px,H2- 28px,H3- 25px,H4- 22px,H5- 20px,H6- 18px

```
h2.Hello H2
h3.Hello H3  ----- here it h2 has 28px and h3 has 25px (28+25=53), total 53px is getting padded in between two tag.  instead i need to pad height of two tag padding value i.e., 28px   
<p>Welcome </p>
h2.Hello H2
h2.Hello H2   ----- here it h2 has 28px and h2 has 28px (28+28=56), total 56px is getting padded in between two tag.  instead i need to pad value i.e., 28px 
<p>Welcome </p>
h4.Hello H4 
H5.Hello H5   ----- here it h4 has 22px and h2 has 20px (22+20=42), total 42px is getting padded in between two tag.instead i need to pad height of two tag padding value i.e., 22px   
<p>Welcome </p>
```

Summary :When we have header tag one after the other need a logic to have a value which is highest among two tag in CSS .

Comment: There is no logic that will do that in CSS. You need javascript

Comment: That is a lot of padding though. You might try margins instead. At least those collapse in the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

You could use CSS and decrease the padding and adjust to how much you'd like.

CSS

```
.examplePadding{
padding-bottom: 50px
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left:50px;
padding-right:50px;
}
```